# mktime does not update the struct tm

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010
This code is compiled as an ANSI C Project

```
int C90Clockadapter_GetCW_ISO8601(const C90Clockadapter * clockadapter, int * calendarweek)
{
    int e = 0;
    struct tm tm;
    char timebuf[64];

    memset( &tm, 0, sizeof( tm ) );
    tm.tm_mday = clockadapter->mDay;
    tm.tm_mon = clockadapter->mMonth;
    tm.tm_year = clockadapter->mYear;

    mktime(&tm);  

    if (0 != strftime(timebuf,sizeof(timebuf),"%W", &tm) ) //i know %W is not ISO8601
    {
        *calendarweek = atoi(timebuf);
    }
    else
    {
        e |= 1;
    }

    return e;
}
```

somehow `mktime(&tm)` does not change the state of `tm`. This behaviour completely does not fit my expectation.

I wrote some unittests that have a self explaining output:

```
4.1.1971 - expected CW 1 but was CW 0
31.12.1992 - expected CW 53 but was CW 0
```

What is wrong with my code - or is there some speciality in windows or with vs2010 and ansi-c that i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeformat was invalid.
mktime returned -1 and that was unhandled.

This snippet shows how to correctly fill the `struct tm`.

```
tm.tm_mday = clockadapter->mDay;
tm.tm_mon = clockadapter->mMonth - 1;
tm.tm_year = clockadapter->mYear - 1900;
```

Answer (score 1):

The references says it won't necessarily modify the timeptr parameter.  You should use the return value.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/

```
time_t mktime (struct tm * timeptr);
```